# How to move data from postgres on Windows to postgres on Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-9.6

I have Postgres DB on machine with Windows OS, also I have virtual machine with Linux (Ubuntu). I need to move data from Windows to Linux.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Backup - restore?

Comment: Yes, backup and restore: https://www.sqlshack.com/migrate-an-sql-database-from-windows-to-linux-using-backup-and-restore-and-smb-protocol/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use below query to restore a database from one server to another

```
pg_dump -C -h SourceServer -U SourceUser  SourceDB | psql -h TargetHost -U TargetUser  TargetDB
```

Password can be used from pgpass.conf

Answer (score 1):

I had to transfer a DB from my local machine ( Windows 11) to an Linux (Ubuntu Bionic) server, so I did the following:

1. Dumped my DB into a backup file with extension .sql by using the following command

- Open the terminal
- Go to the folder where postgresql is installed in my case it was

  ```
  C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin
  ```
- In the terminal write

  ```
  cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin
  ```
- Type the following command, change the <db_name> and <folder_name> as required and press enter.

  ```
  pg_dump.exe -U postgres -d <db_name> -f D:\<folder_name>\<db_name>.sql
  ```
- Enter your password and it will create the backup in the mentioned folder.

---

2. Connect to the Linux Server and copy the <db_name>.sql file

   ```
   scp  D:\<folder_name>\<db_name>.sql  username@ip_address:/<destination_folder>
   ```

---

3. Install postgresql on the server

   ```
   sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
   ```

- Check the status

  ```
  service postgresql status
  ```
- Create DB

  ```
  sudo su postgres
  psql -U postgres -c “create database <db_name>”
  ```
- Import the data from the dump file to this new DB.

  ```
  psql db_name < /path/db_name.sql
  ```